# Is there a function $f$ such that $f(x) =1$ if $x=p/q$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a function $f$ such that satisfied : $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ for } x=\frac{p}{q}\\ 0 \text{ for } x \ne \frac{p}{q} \end{cases}$$ and $q\neq 0$ and $x$ is rational number

Note : I have tried  using Fourier transformation for dirac delta function but it's seems not work.

Comment: Yes, there is such a function. You have just defined it.

Comment: No `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` in titles please.

Comment: If you want a name for the function $f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$ it is the Kronecker delta $\delta(\frac{p}{q} - x)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta.

Comment: @Calle The question is of course very badly worded. If we assume that we want a function as above for one fixed value of $p/q$ then yes, what you said about $\delta$. But it seems unlikely to me that that's actually what was intended; seems clear that we want $f(r)=1$ for _every_ rational $r$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, sure, that is not impossible. Neither is it impossible that the Kronecker delta is actually what he wants (and currently, this is how the question is worded).

Comment: Are p, q integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can define such a function by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ for } x=\frac{p}{q}\\ 0 \text{ for } x \ne \frac{p}{q}. \end{cases}$$

Seriously, the problem seems to be confusion over what's required to define a function. That display *does* define a function - it tells you what $f(x)$ should be for every $x$, which is exactly what's required. A function doesn't have to be given by an algebraic formula...

Comment: c .Ullrich , could edit the tittle of question , it's not clear ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what you're asking...

Comment: no , just a latex formula  , not to change the question, i don't know why it's not clear

Comment: I suspect that you're not going to be able to get a "cases" to look right in a title. And if you _can_ you shouldn't! My advice is to change the title to something like "Is there an $f$ which equals $1$ at every rational and $0$ at every irrational?"

Comment: OK never mind then...

Comment: I edited it , thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is just a restatement
of the problem,
but,
if
$\Delta(x)$
is the non-Dirac delta function

$\Delta(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 \text{ for } x=0\\ 
0 \text{ for } x \ne 0\\
 \end{cases}
$

and
$R$ is the set of
rational numbers
(which, of course,
is countable),
then
$$f(x)
=
\sum_{r \in R} \Delta(x-r)
$$
will do.

Comment: Isn't the set of rationals normally described by $\mathbb Q$, while $\mathbb R$ being reals?

Comment: Your $\delta$ is not a Dirac delta.

Comment: You are right. I will modify my answer.

Comment: @Kristoffer Ryhl: Yep, but I never can remember how to write that R, so I just made it a capital R which I knew was *not* the usual term for the rationals.

Comment: I'd probably have done a capital Q then. `\mathbb{Q}`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to remember that.

Comment: If you can't remember, you can usually pretty quickly find someone who posted a $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$ somewhere. Then you can simply right-click and choose show tex commands.